# How to find man page of operators used in if statement in bash scripting?

Tags: bash, scripting

I was wondering ... there is some operator such as `-f -e -d -s` that I use in bash scripting but how to search for them in manual pages ? what is the command please

example :

```
if [[ -e file2 ]]; then 
      echo "file2 exists"
fi
```

Comment: There's nothing at all specific to `if` about `test` operators. You can use them outside an `if` statement too: `[ -e file2 ] || cp file2.tmpl file2`

Comment: ...the canonical reference, btw, is http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html -- defining those operators *all* POSIX-compliant implementations of `test` must provide.

Comment: Canonical for those supported by POSIX, anyway. There are additional operators supported by `bash` that are only documented in the `bash` man page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command to find the exact list of operators in the bash manual is:

```
$ LESS=+/'^CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS' man bash
```

There is an alternative if you are working inside a bash shell:

```
$ help test
```

Both provide the list of operators inside `test`, `[` and `[[`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually `[` is bash builtin nowadays and `[[` a bash syntax element. While the binary `[` from coreutils might be installed as well, as well as `test`, the man page of `test` or `[` describes the behaviour of that binary not the behaviour of the bash builtin.

Use

```
help [
```

or

```
help [[
```

Keep this in mind for other builtins as well. You can obtain the list of builtins using `compgen -b`.

---

One thing, `[` is an alias of the `test` builtin. You get a far more verbose manual when you type `help test` than the one from `help [`. Thanks [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424552/how-to-find-man-page-of-operators-used-in-if-statement-in-bash-scripting/37424669?noredirect=1#comment62354677_37424669)!.

Comment: `help test` gives more details than `help [`, at least in my bash version.